# Hard integral - does it have a closed form?

Tags: calculus, integration

$$ \int_{-1}^0 \sqrt{ x + \ln  \left( \frac{1}{x+1} \right ) }  ~~~dx$$

All I could do is this:

$$ f(x) = \sqrt{ x + \ln  \left( \frac{1}{x+1} \right ) }  = \sqrt{ x - \ln  \left( {x+1} \right ) }$$

Then:

$$ u = x+ 1 \\ x = u - 1 \\ \Rightarrow du = dx $$

$$\sqrt{ u-1 - \ln  \left(u \right ) } ~~ du$$

But this is a deadend, because I don't know how to continue from this type of function..

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is this from an arclength calculation?

Comment: @epte I don't think so, I would be surprised if this is even a known question because this is my pure imagination, and I am just curious :-)

Comment: @epte: unlikely, this would be for the curve corresponding to the antiderivative of $\sqrt{x-\ln(x+1)-1}$ !?

Comment: The equivalent integral $I_{n-1}=\int_0^1 (-x-\log (1-x))^{n-1} \, dx$ does seem to have an interesting closed form for all integer $n>=1$. $I_{n-1}=(n-1)! \sum _{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k!}\sum _{i=0}^k (-1)^i \binom{k}{i} (-i+k+1)^{k-n}$. See Peter Bala's contribution (Aug 14 2012) to https://oeis.org/A176599. Doesn't appear to help in regard to the present problem.